# Fabric.with Crashlytics causing issues with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

When I run my project in Android Studio it fails for the following reason:

`Error:(190, 18) error: incompatible types: <anonymous Runnable> cannot be converted to Context`

The line in question is:

`Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());`

I've walked through the migration steps for Crashlytics > Fabric 3 times now and I've found a number or sof questions that haven't helped me solve this issue yet.

I have the imports and I have the correct libs. What should I try next?

Comment: do you use the fabric plugin for android studio?

Comment: @Rithe Yep. In fact, I didn't start having this issue until the crashlytics plugin was replaced with the fabric plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We installed the fabric tools from a different computer and that worked.

- 2012 iMac osx 10.10
- Android Studio 1.4.1

Comment: Offtopic: I voted to undelete your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789825/xcode-7-1-immediate-crash-w-no-output on the grounds that it would be better if you answered it than if you deleted. Sure, I could be wrong, but my feeling is, this is a mistake anyone could make while messing around with the "interface" / "launch" entries in the target editor, and others might be helped by knowing what the symptoms are when you do.

Comment: @matt I filled out a thorough answer and undeleted the question. Thanks for the follow up.