# xcode 7.1 immediate crash w no output

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

Preface:

I'm trying to get the iPad pro to run my app at native resolution so I added a Launch Screen file. I set the new controller to be an entry point then after some tweaks I deleted the file and went back to no Launch Screen.

Crash:
I get no output other than `(lldb)`. I typed `bt` into the console and got the following

## output

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xd26faa, 0x000000011351ddbb libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000000011351ddbb libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x0000000112730159 UIKit`+[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 727
    frame #2: 0x0000000112015c7f UIKit`-[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 58
    frame #3: 0x0000000112015fd3 UIKit`-[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
    frame #4: 0x0000000112014851 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1380
    frame #5: 0x0000000112011ba3 UIKit`-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    frame #6: 0x000000011a5b0784 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    frame #7: 0x000000011a5b0af2 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    frame #8: 0x0000000113a85011 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    frame #9: 0x0000000113a7af3c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    frame #10: 0x0000000113a7a3f3 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 867
    frame #11: 0x0000000113a79e08 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    frame #12: 0x00000001120114f5 UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 402
    frame #13: 0x000000011201630d UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 171
  * frame #14: 0x000000010fa23b22 MyApp`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff501e1818) + 146 at main.m:28
    frame #15: 0x00000001179f892d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #16: 0x00000001179f892d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

of course main.m is generic and of no help

## main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

/*
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    //NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = -1;
    @try {
        @autoreleasepool {
            retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException* exception) {
//        NSLog(@"Uncaught exception: %@", exception.description);
//        NSLog(@"Stack trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
    }
    //[pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

What should my next troubleshooting move be?

Comment: **"stop reason = breakpoint 1.1"**  I'd turn off exception breakpoints temporarily and see if anything useful was printed to the debug console.  I'd also look at the device console log to see if it had clues.

Comment: @PhillipMills In that scenario I see "Build Succeeded", a flash of black, and then nothing. Apps closed, no logs :(

Comment: "I set the new controller to be an entry point then after some tweaks I deleted the file and went back to no Launch Screen." Bring back the launch screen. Use a launch storyboard and do not edit it in any way. Set it as your app target's launch interface.

Comment: @matt Still no go. I'm finding out it may have something to do with `__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__` so I'm looking up more on it.

Comment: Found it. I had cleared out "Main Interface" in General and the app was quick-closing because none of the selectors performed existed. Insanity Ensued. Deleting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xcode 7.1 (and many other versions), in the **general settings** for an application, you'll find a number of fields including:

- **Main Interface** *(under Deployment Info)*
- **Launch Screen File** *(under App Icons and Launch Images)*

## Issue

I'm not sure exactly when, but at some point I had confused these two options. As part of a troubleshooting tactic I started to put everything back how it was when the app was working. During that process I encountered this error. The error was trying to tell me, quite ambiguously, that something in my app wasn't responding to an certain (unspecified) selector. I wasn't about to sift through 100+ files so I started working my way backward, again.

## Solution

- Make sure **Main Interface** is a `storyboard` *(File > New > File... > Storyboard)* with an initiation point set.
- Make sure **Launch Screen File** is a `launch screen` *(File > New > File... > Launch Screen)* Note- You can opt out of using a Launch Screen if you don't want / need it. I use one because it's an easy way to get your app to display at the native resolution on an iPhone 6(s) / 6(s)+ / iPad Pro.